# Change state on Superagent request

Tags: reactjs, superagent

I'm trying to change my state in my Request with 'superagent', but the result of the console.log is undefined. Can everyone help me please?

```
componentDidMount(){

    var self = this;

    Request.get('https://api.navitia.io/v1/coverage/fr-idf/stop_areas/stop_area%3AOIF%3ASA%3A59491/departures?')
        .auth('******')
        .end(function(err, res){
            if(err){
                return err;
            }
            let departures = res.body.departures;
            self.setState({body: departures});
        });
    console.log(this.state.departures);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is [usually asynchronous](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate), although it can, in some cases, be synchronous (if called outside of the `react` context -- e.g., if you pass setState to a non-react DOM node/function). In this case, it's set asynchronously, batched with other state updates that might be made in the same tick/frame. If you log `this.state.departures` in, for instance, `componentWillUpdate` or `componentDidUpdate` (but only on the next tick), you'll see your value there. Even if you put your console statement into `setTimeout(console.log(...), 100)`, you'll probably not get `undefined`.

Alternatively, if you need to act on that value and cannot or do not want to use a lifecycle method, you can call `setState` with a callback, like so: `setState((state) => return mutatedState)`. You'll never receive stale state in the callback, such that calling `setState` sequentially will always behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You don't set the `depatures` state, but the `body` state.
2. `setState` *can* be asynchronous, so it's better to put the logging in its callback.

Try this:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  const self = this;

  Request.get('https://api.navitia.io/v1/coverage/fr-idf/stop_areas/stop_area%3AOIF%3ASA%3A59491/departures?')
    .auth('******')
    .end(function(err, res){
      if(err) return err;
      let departures = res.body.departures;
      self.setState({ departures });
  }, () => console.log(this.state.departures));
}
```